# How to disable the default UIMenuItem without affecting messages UIMenuItem?

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

There is a way to disable the default UIMenuItem

[image]

Without affecting messages UIMenuItem?
[image]

*ViewDidLoad:*

```
JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.registerMenuAction(#selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:)))
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [UIMenuItem.init(title: "Delete", action: Selector(("delete")))]
```

Comment: do you want to disable copy - delete etc ?

Comment: @Jack  Yes, also to disable Selectable

Comment: Try this `cell.textView.selectable = false` in `cellForRow method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`cell.textView.selectable = false`
in `cellForRow` method

Comment: Actually, you have to check first if textView is not nil and then set `isSelectable` to false otherwise you get crash when pressing AccessoryButton

Answer (score 1):

Here you choose what will appear when long pressing the messageBubble.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:))) {

        if(messages[indexPath.row].isMediaMessage) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:))) {

        if(messages[indexPath.row].isMediaMessage) {
            return false
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:))) {

        if(messages[indexPath.row].isMediaMessage) {
            return false
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:))) {

        if(messages[indexPath.row].isMediaMessage) {
            return true
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

And then what will happen after you select the item you want,

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {

    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:))) {
        print("deleted")
        print(indexPath.row)

        let messageKey = messages[indexPath.row].keyID

        print("messageKey")
        print(messageKey!)

        messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:))) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

}